# Strange Sql Update behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to update supplier table on both PostgreSQL and MySQL using the following update statement:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS SET CURDEBT = CURDEBT + 10 WHERE ID = 5
```

This works fine as long as the `CURDEBT` column not equals null, if it is null it won't update the record. Does any body have a solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How would you expect NULL + 10 to behave? (NULL == undefined)

Comment: is there any workaround for this

Comment: I have added my answer below - Coalesce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL, NULL is not the same thing as 0. Any operations on a NULL value still yield a NULL result.  NULL + 10 is still NULL.

If you want NULL to automatically turn into "0" in this query, try this (**PostgreSQL**):

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS SET CURDEBT = coalesce(CURDEBT, 0) + 10 WHERE ID = 5
```

Or **MySQL**:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS SET CURDEBT = ifnull(CURDEBT, 0) + 10 WHERE ID = 5
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `coalesce`

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS SET CURDEBT = coalesce(CURDEBT,0) + 10 WHERE ID = 5
```

See [sqlbook](http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-Coalesce-28.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is `COALESCE`:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS
SET CURDEBT = COALESCE(CURDEBT, 0) + 10
WHERE ID = 5
```

Coalesce (MySQL):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Answer (score 3):

That behaviour is exactly what you should expect from SQL, since null + x = null, always.

You can solve it by using the COALESCE function, available in both postgres and mysql, like so:

```
UPDATE SUPPLIERS SET CURDEBT = COALESCE(CURDEBT,0) + 10 WHERE ID = 5
```